# R (data.table): Fast counts of value matches in multiple column

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a fast way to count the number of times a value that appears in one of multiple vectors also appears in multiple other vectors? Here's an example:

```
library(data.table)
names<-c(rep('apple',4),rep('banana',3),rep('cantalope',2),'date')
set.seed(38291)
v1<-data.table(municipality=rep('A',6),village=rep('1',6),
               last=sample(names,6,replace=TRUE),
               middle=sample(names,6,replace=TRUE),id=c(1:6))
v2<-data.table(municipality=rep('A',4),village=rep('2',4),
               last=sample(names,4,replace=TRUE),
               middle=sample(names,4,replace=TRUE),id=c(7:10))
v1
#    municipality village      last    middle id
# 1:            A       1    banana cantalope  1
# 2:            A       1 cantalope    banana  2
# 3:            A       1 cantalope cantalope  3
# 4:            A       1     apple     apple  4
# 5:            A       1    banana     apple  5
# 6:            A       1     apple     apple  6
v2
#    municipality village      last    middle id
# 1:            A       2      date cantalope  7
# 2:            A       2     apple      date  8
# 3:            A       2 cantalope    banana  9
# 4:            A       2     apple cantalope 10
DT = rbind(v1, v2)
```

I want to count the number of family ties that cross between individuals in village 1 and village 2. Cross-village family ties are defined by whether an individual's last OR middle name ('last' or 'middle') matches someone's last or middle name in another village. In this example, the individual with id=1 who lives in village 1 has three family members in village 2 (those with ids 7, 9, and 10) because he shares at least one name with them. I then want to create a dyadic dataset of villages where the ties between villages are defined by the number of family ties that cross between those villages. So, in this example the final dataset would look like:

```
dyads<-data.table(v1='1',v2='2',ties=3+3+3+2+3+2)
dyads
   v1 v2 ties
1:  1  2   16
```

Is there an efficient way to calculate this 'ties' number? I've written an inefficient for loop to do this, but I have a massive dataset (~ 50 million individuals in 40000 villages).

Comment: So `last = 'banana'` is fine to match to `middle = 'banana'`?

Comment: That's right. Matches should be last-last, last-middle, middle-last or middle-middle

Comment: And do you really have separate `data.table`s for each village? or one big `data.table`

Comment: I have one big data.table with approximately 55 million observations, 40,000 villages, and 1500 municipalities. I only need to calculate the 'ties' variable for villages in the same municipality.

Comment: Are you not concerned about over-matching? do you want to build in using some information about `id` to limit this?

Comment: yes, good catch, thanks. Each pair of individuals (with unique ids) can have at most 1 'tie' between them. So, for example, a pair of individuals with names 'apple apple' and 'apple apple' would only count as 1 tie, not 4.

Comment: is `id` unique in the population? i.e. is it possible to have `village` 3 `id` 2 and `village` 10 `id` 2?

Comment: I just created the ids myself, so each id is unique in the population

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An update inspired by Frank's answer:

```
meltDT = 
  #use unique to eliminate last+middle duplication
  unique(melt(DT, measure.vars = c('last', 'middle'), 
              id.vars = c('village', 'id'), value.name = 'name'),
         by = c('village', 'id', 'name'))

#framework of output -- one row for each pair of villages
out.dt = with(DT, CJ(village, village, unique = TRUE))[V2 > V1]

setkey(meltDT, village)
setindex(meltDT, name)
#set indices to facilitate merges on names
out.dt[ , {
  ties := 
    #unique here eliminates matching on both last & middle
    uniqueN(meltDT[.(.BY$V1)][meltDT[.(.BY$V2)], on = 'name', 
                              allow.cartesian = TRUE, nomatch = 0L],
            by = c('id', 'i.id'))
}, by = .(V1, V2)]
out.dt
#    V1 V2 ties
# 1:  1  2   16
```

Comment: Maybe cut down on # joins with by=V1 and then something like `DT[.BY][V2, on='last', nomatch=0, .N, by=.EACHI]$N + ...`

Comment: If the OP didn't comment here yet, they might not be pingable like that, fyi. I think the two `meltDT[.(.BY$Vx)]` should use `j` to only include the cols you need (which I'm guessing isn't all of them?). I imagine there may be a tradeoff between your way and mine depending on how many (V1,V2) pairs there are vs how many distinct names (since those are the big `by=` groups that the two answers use). Aside from speed, one or the other may hit memory problems, since I have CJ and you have allow.cartesian...

Comment: @Frank agreed... probably best to create copies of the full `data.table` that only have the targeted columns

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This is fantastic! Thank you @MichaelChirico and Frank so much for your help. Seems to be working great, and MUCH faster than my previous code.

Answer (score 3):

This extends to 3+ villages, but will be quite slow:

```
DT = rbind(v1, v2)

matches = melt(DT, id="id", measure.vars=c("middle","last"))[, 
  CJ(id1 = id, id2 = id)[id1 < id2]
, by=value]

matches[DT, on=.(id1 = id), v1 := i.village ]
matches[DT, on=.(id2 = id), v2 := i.village ]

unique(matches[, !"value"])[v2 != v1, .N, by=.(v1, v2)]
#    v1 v2  N
# 1:  1  2 16
```

So it finds individuals who match (even if they're in the same village) and the OP's desired result is just a summary stat computed with this set of matches.

Comment: I couldn't quite wrap my head fully around what you were trying, so I made my own version. Curious how they compare at scale...